# Context-Free Grammar construction when order isn't specified

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm having trouble constructing a grammar for

> **L={wϵ{a,b}|n<sub>a</sub>(w)≠n<sub>b</sub>(w)}**

So I need to construct a grammar for the language wherein the number of a's does not equal the number of b's. The farthest I've attempted is splitting the language into

> **L={wϵ{a,b}*|n<sub>a</sub>(w)>n<sub>b</sub>(w)}∪{wϵ{a,b}*|n<sub>a</sub>(w)<n<sub>b</sub>(w)}**

but I don't know where to go from there. What makes this problem challenging is that no order is specified so I don't even know where to begin.

Thus, the second part of my questions is if there is any general rule I should follow when dealing with languages that don't stipulate an order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The first step in your grammar should decide whether $n_{\mathtt{a}} > n_{\mathtt{b}}$ or $n_{\mathtt{a}} < n_{\mathtt{b}}$, and then the two "halves" of your grammar will then construct appropriate strings.  [This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388367/8348) might help you.

Comment: Thank you. The related question helped immensely.